# Why do i get: org.apache.camel.TypeConversionException: java.io.FileNotFoundException:

Tags: spring, apache-camel

I am using camel version 2.11.1 within the spring context. here are my routes and beans.

```
      <route>
        <from uri="file:/directory?move=archive&amp;maxMessagesPerPoll=25&amp;delay=1000&amp;eagerMaxMessagesPerPoll=true" />
        <to uri="seda:updateSomething" />
      </route>
      <route>
        <from uri="seda:updateSomething?concurrentConsumers=100&amp;limitConcurrentConsumers=false" />
        <process ref="updateSomething" />
        <to uri="seda:updateSomethingElse" />
      </route>
      <route>
        <from uri="seda:updateSomethingElse?concurrentConsumers=100&amp;limitConcurrentConsumers=false" />
        <process ref="updateSomethingElse" />
    </route>
```

My Beans:

```
<bean id="updateSomething" class="project.Class1" scope="prototype">
</bean>
<bean id="updateSomethingElse" class="project.Class2" scope="prototype">
</bean>
```

When this is started it works without any problems.  The more files that are being processed I start getting the error and eventually more and more of these happen more often as time goes on:

```
    org.apache.camel.TypeConversionException: Error during type conversion from type: java.io.File to the required type: byte[] with value /pathto/file due java.io.FileNotFoundException:
```

It seems as though I am processing each file properly, but why am I getting this error...more importantly what do I need to do differently to not receive this error.

project.Class1 & project.Class2 have same implementation. Only showing Class 1 since they are the same.

```
 public final class Class1 implements Processor {

     public void process(Exchange exchange) throws Exception { 
            ...

    }
 }
```

Comment: It seems like a File doesn't exist and so you can't get the bytes. Look at the stack trace and find which service provides that feature.

Comment: can you please show us the implementation of the 'project.class1' and 'project.class2'

Comment: Gut feeling is the Camel File Component is grabbing the same file with another thread.  This maybe due to acknowledgement process the File Component is doing with the file system.  There would be a fraction of a second that the acknowledgement didn't happen so a second thread grabs the same file.  I will have to added some logging to see if I can capture this.

Answer (score 0):

Try streamCache="true" in your CamelContext.